# Background changing over javascript and var

Tags: javascript, php, css

I'm working on my server an I will make a loading screen for my server (gmod) and the special is then the loading screen coming it opens up a URL and in this URL I can usually grab the steam id of the user who is joining my server and then the loading screen use his own id avatar and others...

so you can realize that so a normal game like counter strike and you will join a server and then the loading screen comes it open up a URL and over the URL (ht tp://blabla.com/index.php?steamid=%s) you send automatic the steam id and others...

My loading screen also the index.php its look like this then its open from the game -> loading screen

[image]

my loading screen also the index.php can grab the map-name and server-name. so I have think about and every game with the same background isn't terrible so here is my idea:

when a maps loads lets say cs_office  than its search in the sub-folder 
 for'backgrounds/cs_office/...'  when it has found the folder  -> set the background path to this  -->> else use the default background --

that is the main.js (the script who grab the id)

[image]

so lets say, i have make a var now i will make the background, but cant because its a extern.css file and i use to change it via php and the wrong thing is that i can't use php so i must use javascript i have to first rename the style.css to style.php and have included it `<?php include 'style.php'; ?>`

and now the special i try to become the map-name into the path: (style.php)

[image]

so my idea is that, I will make for every map a folder with 6 screenshots of the map and then the folder doesn't exist from the map - use the default background folder with 6  images

[image]

it's a dynamic background so changing between 6 images..

ok the last I will make when available that every map loads her own background ..

so I have created a folder for the map de_dolls

```
(http://mdettt.bugs3.com/TTTindex/Crystal_Load/backgrounds/de_dolls/)
```

`edit:` theres my `main.js` part

```
function GameDetails( servername, serverurl, mapname, maxplayers, steamid, gamemode ) 
{
 document.getElementById( "s-name" ).innerHTML = servername;
 var maap = document.getElementById( "s-map" ).innerHTML = mapname;
 document.getElementById( "s-mode" ).innerHTML = gamemode;
}
```

css as php part:

```
#background-scroll { width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:-10;}
#bg1 {background: url('backgrounds/<script type="text/javascript"> document.write(mapn) </script>/1.jpg;'); background-size: 100% auto; background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#bg2 {background: url('backgrounds/<script type="text/javascript"> document.write(mapn) </script>/2.jpg; ?>'); background-size: 100% auto; background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#bg3 {background: url('backgrounds/<script type="text/javascript"> document.write(mapn) </script>/3.jpg; ?>'); background-size: 100% auto; background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#bg4 {background: url('backgrounds/<script type="text/javascript"> document.write(mapn) </script>/4.jpg; ?>'); background-size: 100% auto; background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#bg5 {background: url('backgrounds/<script type="text/javascript"> document.write(mapn) </script>/5.jpg; ?>'); background-size: 100% auto; background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#bg6 {background: url('backgrounds/<script type="text/javascript"> document.write(mapn) </script>/6.jpg; ?>'); background-size: 100% auto; background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

and some parameters how the mapname will recieved...

```
  <ul id="server-list">
      <li><img src="images/server-name.png" alt="Server Name" /> <span id="s-name">Server Name</span></li><!-- Dynamically adds the server name -->
      <li><img src="images/server-mode.png" alt="Game Mode" /> <span id="">Trouble in Terrorist Town</span></li><!-- Dynamically adds game mode name -->
      <li><img src="images/server-map.png" alt="Map Name" /> <span id="s-map">Server Map</span></li><!-- Dynamically adds map name -->
  </ul>
```

--

```
<div id="background-scroll"><!-- Add Backgrounds so we can have multiple ones -->
<div id="bg1"></div><!-- BG 1 -->
<div id="bg2"></div><!-- BG 2 -->
<div id="bg3"></div><!-- BG 3 -->
<div id="bg4"></div><!-- BG 4 -->
<div id="bg5"></div><!-- BG 5 -->
<div id="bg6"></div><!-- BG 6 -->
</div>
```

Comment: No thanks for me...Seeing long text...i read none...except the last line :P

Comment: Please re-word, we don't need an entire backstory.

Answer (score 0):

Wall of text. Oh shit. I just read the headline and answer it.

```
$("#changeBackground").click(function() {
    $("body").css({"background-color" : yourColor});
)};
```

Uses jQuery. Its easier than pure JS.

Comment: hmm but now i am not so a guru an dont know how :S i will only "chase" the var into a if and then his ohwn backgrounds exist than it changes the paht of the sytle.php...

Comment: @Nick R exactly what i thought when i wrote this. :D

Comment: nick you have understand it wrong i will that i ask over a if exist : if a folder exist with this name under backgrounds change the var mapn -> {background: url('backgrounds/<script type="text/javascript"> document.write(mapn) </script>/1.jpg;'); background-size: 100% auto; background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;}